# Why are they distributing money to the customers at the ticket collecting point?

Tags: plot-explanation, magic-mike-xxl

Why are they distributing money to each customer at the ticket collecting point in *Magic Mike XXL* (2015)?

[image]

Comment: i presume for them to throw at the strippers?

Comment: To make it rain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are one-dollar bills, to shower the strippers with.  I presume that each of the women paid in advance or at the table, and are just receiving the same amount of money in one-dollar bills.

[image]